# There is debug.log file created in my angular-cli project. How is it created and what's its use?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This is debug.log file:

> [0110/160818:ERROR:tcp_listen_socket.cc(76)] Could not bind socket to
>   127.0.0.1:6004 [0110/160818:ERROR:node_debugger.cc(86)] Cannot start debugger server [0111/233417:ERROR:tcp_listen_socket.cc(76)] Could not
>   bind socket to 127.0.0.1:6004 [0111/233417:ERROR:node_debugger.cc(86)]
>   Cannot start debugger server
>   [0113/120522:ERROR:tcp_listen_socket.cc(76)] Could not bind socket to
>   127.0.0.1:6004 [0113/120522:ERROR:node_debugger.cc(86)] Cannot start debugger server [0113/122245:ERROR:tcp_listen_socket.cc(76)] Could not
>   bind socket to 127.0.0.1:6004 [0113/122245:ERROR:node_debugger.cc(86)]
>   Cannot start debugger server
>   [0120/171545:ERROR:tcp_listen_socket.cc(76)] Could not bind socket to
>   127.0.0.1:6004 [0120/171545:ERROR:node_debugger.cc(86)] Cannot start debugger server [0207/173408:ERROR:tcp_listen_socket.cc(76)] Could not
>   bind socket to 127.0.0.1:6004 [0207/173408:ERROR:node_debugger.cc(86)]
>   Cannot start debugger server

Comment: Have you found a way to resolve this issue? I have been trying for a couple of hours now... no luck so far

Comment: Not yet. I just want to ask how this file is created and whats its use?

Comment: It's been three years. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why they are being created (In my case, they are everywhere!), but I found how to ignore them ;)

Add the following to your `.gitignore` file. Problem solved!

```
**/debug.log
```

Comment: too bad somebody committed it in my team.

Comment: @ZameerFouzan just delete it when you commit the updated gitignore file :)